# Segue transitions to the wrong page Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to create a series of pages that work in tandem using custom segues. These segues work fine until I have them execute in a certain series. From VC1 I go to VC2 via the default modal segue (it pops up over the original segue). Then, from VC2 I go to VC3 using a custom horizontal segue (code below). Finally, I go back from VC3 to VC1 using a custom unwind horizontal segue. The problem is that when I go back to VC1, VC2 appears instead. I checked and ViewDidLoad does not execute in VC2 when it appears, but I can still interact with it when triggered. My best guess as to what is happening is that VC2 covers VC1 so when I go back to VC1, VC2 is displayed on top of it. Even if this is the problem, I don't know how to fix it. Code below:

Horizontal Segue:

```
class HorizontalSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source as UIViewController
        let dst = self.destination as UIViewController

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },
            completion: { finished in
                src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Unwind Horizontal Segue:

```
class UnwindHorizontalSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source as UIViewController
        let dst = self.destination as UIViewController

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, belowSubview: src.view)
        src.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
            src.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)
        },
            completion: { finished in
                src.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: “My best guess” Why guess? The View Debugger will tell you exactly what the situation is.

Comment: And in any case everything you’re doing is illegal. You can go shoving view controller views around like that. If the goal is a custom presentation animation  there’s a right way to do that and what you’re doing isn’t it. And your custom segue structure is wrong too.

Comment: @matt Well, telling me what I'm doing is wrong isn't very helpful on its own. What is the "right way to do it"?

Comment: How to write a custom transition animation for a presented / dismissed view controller is well documented and has been explained many times here and elsewhere including by me. That’s not the point. The point is you’re getting yourself into an incoherent view controller situation and now you’re realizing it.

Comment: @matt I did, in fact, figure this out via a relatively upvoted stack overflow post. What is it that I am doing wrong? I do want to know what it is that I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: @matt I have looked at other documentation and I still can't figure out what is wrong with my code. That is why I posted this to stack. Telling me that what I am doing is wrong provides ZERO help because the reason I am posting this question is that I know that what I am doing is wrong, just not why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that you said `ViewDidLoad` is not called for VC2. Please see if `ViewDidAppear` (or will appear) is being called instead.

`ViewDidLoad` is only called when the view loads (initially, when it wasn't there before). `ViewDidAppear` should fire always, when the view is brought into the user's screen.

After that, log `dst` in your custom `UIStoryBoardSegue`. If that's an instance of VC2, you are simply pushing the wrong view controller.

I also see you're using `src.present` and `src.dismiss` in your `UIStoryboardSegue`. This means you're not actually pushing views, but presenting them "on top" of an active view controller. Try to rethink that logic, since this is very much likely where the problem lies.

I would rather try and push the view controllers (normally, instead of 'presenting' them) and change the `UIStoryboardSegue` appearance to fake the animation if that's what you're after.